# How to set background color of modal in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, popup, modal-popup

I want to set background color in whole modal. How to do it..?

Please help me...

See the below code....

```
    <div id="popup-modal" class="abc">
<p>A</p>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .modal-popup._inner-scroll .modal-inner-wrap
    {
        top: 20%;
    }
    .modal-slide._inner-scroll .modal-content
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .abc
    {
        display: none;
    }
}​
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],

        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                slideshowSpeed: 8000,

                //title: 'popup modal title',
                /*buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
*/            };

            setTimeout(function () {

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

            $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            $(".modal-footer").css("border-top","0");
            $(".modal-popup._inner-scroll .modal-inner-wrap").css("width", 700);
        }, 1000 );

        });


</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

> $('.modal-popup._inner-scroll
>   .modal-inner-wrap').css('background-color','black');

```
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],

    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 8000,

            //title: 'popup modal title',
            /*buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
    */  };

        setTimeout(function () {

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));

        $('#popup-modal').modal('openModal');
        $(".modal-footer").css("border-top","0");
        $('.modal-popup._inner-scroll .modal-inner-wrap').css('background-color','black');
    }, 1000 );

    });
```

Comment: and what is the option for the popup size ?

Comment: @LachezarRaychev $('.modal-popup._inner-scroll .modal-inner-wrap').css('width','450px');

Comment: no property in options for that ? ?